# How can I update my photo on the Sitecore MVP Directory?

Tags: community, mvp

I am (used to be) a Sitecore MVP and I appear in the [Sitecore MVP Directory](https://mvp.sitecore.com/Directory).

How can I upload or change my photo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the [MVP Directory](https://mvp.sitecore.com/Directory) is using [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/) to display the photos of the MVPs.

To upload your photo please register an account with Gravatar and associate a photo with your email address.

If your photo already appears, but you want to change it then it means you should already have a Gravatar account. In this case, please log in and change your photo there.

If you don't know what email address the [MVP Directory](https://mvp.sitecore.com/Directory) is using or you need to change the email address, please contact the Sitecore MVP Team at mvp@sitecore.com